# Restrict Access to Certain Class Methods Based on Selected Generic Type

Tags: typescript, generics, es6-class

I have this generic Typescript class:

```js
export class Lexicon<T extends Dictionary> {
    private action: PublicDictionaryActions | PersonalDictionaryActions;
    
    constructor(private type: T) {
        this.type = type;
        this.action = type.isPublicResource
            ? initialisePublicActions()
            : initialisePersonalActions();
    }

    isPublicDictionary(type: Actions): type is PublicDictionaryActions {
        return this.type.isPublicResource;
    }

    saveWord(): boolean {
        if (this.isPublicDictionary(this.action) && "save" in this.action) {
            let isSaved = false
            this.action.save = () => {
                console.log("test save function");
                isSaved = true
            };
            this.action.save();
            return isSaved 
        } else {
            console.log();
            throw new Error("This method does not exist for the created type.")
        }
    }
    // rest of the methods follow... 
    
}
```

which restricts the generic type to only types that are part of `Dictionary`, its type being the union of `PublicDictionary` and `PersonalDictionary`:

```js
export type PublicDictionary = {
    name: WordBook;
    isPublicResource: boolean;
    canShuffle: boolean;
    bannerImage?: string;
    wordList?: Array<Term>;
    apiKey?: string;
};

export type PersonalDictionary = {
    name: WordBook;
    isPublicResource: boolean;
    canShuffle: boolean;
    wordCount?: number;
    wordList?: Array<Term>;
};
```

Now, depending on whether the dictionary type is public or personal, the methods that can be invoked will vary.

```js
export type Actions = PublicDictionaryActions | PersonalDictionaryActions;

export type PublicDictionaryActions = Pick<IDictionary, "save" | "setCredentials" | "shuffle">;

export type PersonalDictionaryActions = Pick<IDictionary, "delete" | "update" | "shuffle">;

export interface IDictionary {
    update(): void;
    delete(): void;
    shuffle(): void;
    save(): void;
    shuffle(): void;
    setCredentials?(): void;
}
```

As shown here, a public dictionary will have the methods `save`, `shuffle`, `setCredentials` . On the other hand, a personal dictionary will have the methods `delete`, `update`, and `shuffle`. When a new instance of the class is created, the `actions` private class member will be assigned with a set of functions that matches the generic type, these are initialised as empty functions in the beginning. With that out of the way, I would like to direct your attention to one of the class methods:

```js
    saveWord(): boolean {
        if (this.isPublicDictionary(this.action) && "save" in this.action) {
            let isSaved = false
            this.action.save = () => {
                console.log("test save function");
                isSaved = true
            };
            this.action.save();
            return isSaved 
        } else {
            console.log();
            throw new Error("This method does not exist for the created type.")
        }
    }
```

Say I instantiate the class with `PublicDictionary` and call `saveWord()`, it will do a quick check to see if the `save` object property (function) exists. If it does, the function will be defined and called. Otherwise, an error will be thrown.

```js
const lexicon1 = new Lexicon<PublicDictionary>({...})
lexicon1.saveWord() // OK

const lexicon2 = new Lexicon<PersonalDictionary>({...})
lexicon2.saveWord() // Error thrown
```

I've never done something like this before and, admittedly, the logic just seems flawed.

Is this a viable approach? How can I enforce a stricter check so that `saveWord` cannot be accessed when it isn't available in the first place?

Comment: Usual way is just to have different child classes for different data types.

Comment: Yes, I have considered that. The reason I'm doing this is to make the class as reusable as possible, as in just one class file

Comment: Classes are making your program worse.